# Installing WAS 7 on Linux using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, putty, ibm-was

I am trying to install WAS7 using command line via putty and I am getting the following error:

`[root@TVMSLD tools]# ./imcl install com.ibm.rational.was.v70.extension_1.0.0.20080911_1339 -repositories /home/admin/Softwares/WAS7.0/WAS70 -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/V70/BASE -sharedResourcesDirectory /opt/IBM/InstallationManager/IMShared -acceptLicense -showProgress
                 25%                50%                75%                100%
------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
............................................................................
ERROR: The installation package 'IBMÂ® WebSphereÂ® Application Server Version 7.0 Test Environment' requires components supplied by other packages.
The required components might be supplied by the specified features of the following installation packages:
Package: Rational Application Developer 7.5.0 -- Features: Tools for WebSphereÂ® Application Server, version 7.0`

I tried the command with repository path like `/home/admin/Softwares/WAS7.0/WAS70/disk1` and also `/home/admin/Softwares/WAS7.0/WAS70/disk1/diskTag.inf`

But I am getting the same error. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is not standalone server, but test environment provided with Rational Application Developer. It can only be installed via RAD installation together with RAD.

See more info about the standalone developers version [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012950).